# US Tax Return Forms to fill for NRE Account

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, india, non-resident

I am really confused about what forms I have to fill and submit for my 2015 Tax return in USA. I am an Indian lived in USA for whole 2015 tax year.

I have a joint NRE account with my spouse in India with SBI. I have incurred some interest on that account for the FDs I made during 2015.

The total value of the NRE account exceed $50,000. Interest earned on those FDs do not exceed $1500, $1192 to be specific (converted from INR to USD, rate used from [US Treasury](https://www.fiscal.treasury.gov/fsreports/rpt/treasRptRateExch/currentRates.htm)).

**Do I have to file Form 8938?**

**Do I also have to fill FBAR form from their [website](http://bsaefiling.fincen.treas.gov/main.html)?**

Since my total ($10 1099-INT + 67 1099-DIV + $1192 Interest from Foreign bank account) interest is less than $1500, I am assuming I do not have to fill Schedule B.

**Which line of form 1040 I enter this foreign bank interest into?**

I went through FATCA information on IRS website. But clueless.

Please help.